# Unable to make POST REQUEST with html template through Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a `post request`, I have created the models as well, but for some reason, it is giving me the following error

[image]

I understand that this mean there is some mistyped, but when I check the html and views.py, I don't see any mistake, everything should be in order

**financiamiento.html**

```
{% extends "Portafolio/layout.html" %}

{%block content %}
<br>
<div class="text-center">
    <form action="{% url 'financiamiento'%}" method="POST" style="max-width:800px;margin:auto;">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h1 class="mt-5">Perspectiva Financiera</h1>
        <h1 class="h3 mb-10 mt-2">Financiamiento</h1>
        
        <label class="sr-only"></label>
        <input name= "MontoProyecto" type="text" id="MontoProyecto" placeholder="Monto Aporte Proyecto"class="form-control">
        
        <label class="sr-only"></label>
        <input name= "MontoPropio" type="text" id="MontoPropio" placeholder="Monto Aporte Propio"class="form-control">
        
        <label class="sr-only"></label>
        <input name="MontoBanca" type="text" id="MontoBanca" placeholder="Monto Aporte Banca"class="form-control">
        
        <label class="sr-only"></label>
        <input name="MontoPublico" type="text" id="MontoPublico" placeholder="Monto Aporte Publico"class="form-control">        
        
        <div class="d-grid gap-2 mt-3">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Proyecto, Financiamiento

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render (request, "Portafolio/index.html",{
        "financiamiento":Financiamiento.objects.all()
    })

def registroproyecto(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        NombreProyecto = request.POST.get('NombreProyecto')
        ResponsableProyecto = request.POST.get('ResponsableProyecto')
        EvaluadorProyecto = request.POST.get('EvaluadorProyecto')
        DescripcionProyecto = request.POST.get('DescripcionProyecto')

        Proyecto.objects.create(NombreProyecto=NombreProyecto, ResponsableProyecto=ResponsableProyecto, EvaluadorProyecto=EvaluadorProyecto, DescripcionProyecto=DescripcionProyecto)
        return redirect("/Portafolio")
    
    return render (request, "Portafolio/RegistroProyecto.html")

def financiamiento(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        MontoProyecto = request.POST.get('MontoProyecto')
        MontoPropio = request.POST.get('MontoPropio')
        MontoBanca = request.POST.get('MontoBanca')
        MontoPublico = request.POST.get('MontoPublico')

        Financiamiento.objects.create(MontoProyecto=MontoProyecto, MontoPropio=MontoPropio, MontoBanca=MontoBanca, MontoPublico=MontoPublico)
        return redirect("/Portafolio")
    
    return render (request, "Portafolio/Financiamiento.html")
```

Also, something draw my attention, when I made the `Financiamiento table`, when I checked with the django admin, it didn't me allow to put input data, that is normal?

[image]

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Proyecto(models.Model):
    NombreProyecto = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ResponsableProyecto = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    EvaluadorProyecto = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    DescripcionProyecto = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Financiamiento(models.Model):
    MontoProyecto = models.IntegerField
    MontoPropio = models.IntegerField
    MontoBanca = models.IntegerField
    MontoPublico = models.IntegerField
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Proyecto, Financiamiento
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Proyecto)
admin.site.register(Financiamiento)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `models.py` all fields you have are `IntegerField`s. So, in your `views.py` you should convert the elements from `string` to integers first:

```py
def financiamiento(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        MontoProyecto = int(request.POST.get('MontoProyecto'))
        MontoPropio = int(request.POST.get('MontoPropio'))
        MontoBanca = int(request.POST.get('MontoBanca'))
        MontoPublico = int(request.POST.get('MontoPublico'))

        Financiamiento.objects.create(MontoProyecto=MontoProyecto, MontoPropio=MontoPropio, MontoBanca=MontoBanca, MontoPublico=MontoPublico)
        return redirect("/Portafolio")
    
    return render (request, "Portafolio/Financiamiento.html")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, though I solve it in another way, basically in models.py it just left the pararenthesis of the Integer Values with (null=True, blank=True).

I don't doubt that your solution also could work, but I also thanks to you so much for your response !